# Magento 2: Add custom module JavaScript code in head tag

Tags: magento2

My requirement is to append magento 2 custom module JavaScript code inside the `<head>` tag for all the web pages.

Comment: do you want to add code in head tag ? on all pages ?

Comment: yes @NaveedAsim

Comment: Do you want to add .js file in head?

Comment: No, @SukumarGorai my actual requirement is to append javascript code in head.

Comment: Can you update your js code which you want to add in head?

Answer (score 2):

Create `Vendor/moduleName/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>

        <script src="js/test.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Goto **Content** -> **Design** -> **Configuration**
2. Then edit the theme you are using for your store.
3. Goto section **HTML Head** and add your script to **Scripts and Style**
   Sheets like below:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

in admin Go to

> Content->Design

section and there you can add code in head section. like in here [Design Head](https://prnt.sc/kygaxp)